# Iterative Statements

Tags: loops, for-loop, iteration, expression

So, I have been studying iterative statements for a report. While I was reading, I came across the developmental history of definite iteration and eventually learn the for loop. We know that the syntax for the for loop in C,C++, and java is

```
for (expression1; expression2; expression3)
   statement
```

And it says here that we can omit any of the expression and that it is legal to have a for loop that look like this

```
for (;;)
```

My question is how does that work? I cant find any more resources for this one.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop declared as:

```
for (init-statement; condition; iteration-expression) body;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
init-statement;
while (condition) {
   body;
   iteration-expression;
}
```

It's easy to see how `init-statement` or `iteration-expression` could be omitted.  If the `condition` is omitted, it is assumed to be `true`.

A reasonable resource that explains this is the *Explanation* section of the [for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) documentation at cppreference.com.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, for (;;) is legal, but you will need to put something inside the body of that for loop, otherwise the loop will never stop.

```
int counter = 0;
int limit = 5;

for (;;) {
    if (counter > limit) break;
    counter++;
}
```